# Use function on a DataModule

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a datamodule (TfDB) I wanted to add this function to it

```
 Function GetZone(zone :string):string;
```

When i try to run it i get this error...
Unsatisfied forward of external declaration : TfDB.GetZone

```
unit MyDataModule;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB;

type
  TfDB = class(TDataModule)
    dbconnection: TADOConnection;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
          Function GetZone(zone :string):string;
  end;

var
  fDB: TfDB;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}

{$R *.dfm}

  Function GetZone(zone:string):string;
  begin
  if zone = 'FLayout1' then
        result := '1';
  if zone = 'FLayout2' then
      result := '2';
  if zone = 'FLayout3' then
      result := '3';
  if zone = 'FLayout4' then
      result := '4' ;
  if zone = 'FBoneYard' then
      result := 'BoneYard';
  if zone = 'FShop' then
      result := 'shop';
  if zone = 'FMisc' then
      result := 'Misc' ;
  end;

end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the implementation section you need to declare the function as being a method of the class:

```
function TfDB.GetZone(zone:string):string;
begin
  ....
end;
```

Your declaration looked like this:

```
function GetZone(zone:string):string;
begin
  ....
end;
```

And that defines a stand-alone function rather than a method of the class.

Comment: Or click on GetZone in TfDB class and press Ctrl-Shift-c to avto create function.

Comment: @GJ. In my opinion it is important to understand the language, and be able to interpret the error messages that the compiler emits. The IDE's code completion is very helpful but is no substitute for understanding.

Comment: @David Heffernan. Agree, but when you start to use code completion it is faster and more accurate.